# Algorithm to generalize varying datasets to a coordinates system to show as a graph

Tags: java, algorithm, swing

I am working on a Graph visualizer toolkit which scans a text file and shows it as a line Graph on a jPanel. The format of valid a text file is:

```
     Title: <graph title>
     YLabel: <y-axis label>
     XLabel: <x-axis label>
     XStart: <x-axis start value>
     XInterval: <x-axis interval value>
     <data>
```

At this point, I've already validated and stored the values needed for the graph. So basically what I need to do now is generalize the XStart, XInterval and data value to a coordinate system to fit the jPanel, GraphBoard, as the data can and will vary from one file to another.

I did some thinking and thought about using some if-else statements to filter the data and drawing separate graphs for each, I wanna say, type of the data. But immediately discarded it because the process would be repetitive. And right now I'm stuck trying to come up with a brilliant algorithm that will, well cover all kinds of datasets. I hope I explained myself well enough. here is the code i have so far:

```
    public class Coordinator {

    public final static double UNIT = 20;

    protected double xStartCoords, xIntervalCoords, xStart, xInterval;
    protected Double[] yValuesCoords, yValues;
    protected int index = 0;
    protected Double maxYValue, range;

    public Coordinator(double xStart, double xInterval, Double[] yValues) {
        this.xStart = xStart;
        this.xInterval = xInterval;
        this.yValues = yValues;
        xyz();
    }
    public void xyz() {
        //code needed
    }

    }
```

And here are some valid text files:

1.

```
    Title: Effect of Age on Ability
    YLabel: Ability
    XLabel: Age
    XStart: 0
    XInterval: 15
    0, 3, 4.2, 7, 5.1, 10, 3.2
```

2.

```
    Title: Difference between Fly Weights
    YLabel: Weight
    XLabel: Age
    XStart: 0.25
    XInterval: 0.025
    100.02, 100.03, 99.98, 99.99, 100.01, 100.02, 100.05, 100.06, 100.07, 100.01, 100.00, 99.98, 99.97, 99.96
```

3.

```
    Title: Inverse expansion
    YLabel: Size
    XLabel: Time
    XStart: 0
    XInterval: 100000
    0, 20000, 30000, 35000, 40000, 43000, 50000, 60000, 62000, 90000
```

So you see where I'm having trouble. A few suggestions to tackle this would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm to scale x and scale y ?

Comment: Yes. Scale x(xInterval) and y(data) in respect to the panel depending on the number of y's.

Comment: Does this make sense : xPixlesPerUnit = chartWidth(in pixles) / xRange  where xRange is (xInterval * numberOfYs) ?

Comment: A bit, can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: Are we talking about line graphs? I'd make a `GeneralPath` of the points the use an `AffineTransform` to scale the general path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to scale the data to the required chart dimensions. 
In other words calculate what is the representation in pixels for a data unit.
For x axis you could use : 
xPixlesPerUnit = chartWidth / xRange  
where xRange is (xInterval * numberOfYs).  
Applied to text file #1 , assuming you want the chart to be 1000 pixels wide: 
xRange = 15 * 7 = 105 , so 105 units should be 1000 pixels wide 
xPixlesPerUnit = 1000/105 = 9.52 
This means that last x (=105) will be plotted at 105*95.2  = 1000.

You handle Y scale similarly, where 
yRange = yMax - yMin

This is the basic idea. There are many implementation issues to handle like rounding, margins, negative axis (or having more than one quadrant).

Comment: Will get back to you after testing this.

Comment: Feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Okay so I got the xPixlesPerUnit  and yPixlesPerUnit, for file #1, and width: 600 height: 250 as such
xPixlesPerUnit  = 5.142857
yPixlesPerUnit = 22.727272
Now in order to draw a line, what do we have to get the x and y coordinates? Thats what ive been trying to do

Comment: Okay I tried that but didnt work. gonna start from scratch to draw all of it in.